# Implement Rest API within another Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, rest, web-services

Hei,

is there a way to host a Rest API within another webservice / mirror the API?

The problem is, that I have a tool which can not authenticate against the Rest API, so I want to build another webservice to handle the authentication, but all other Rest requests should be handed over to the Rest API.

Is there a simple solution to this, without implementing every function of the Rest API to my new Webservice?

Comment: So -- you want to hack your own API??

Comment: It'll work, but it's really not easy. For **every** rest call, you should first ask the first api if the user is authenticated then route your request to the other api... I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Maybe this is an x-y-Question. Why not work on the problem that the tool cannot authenticate? Can you lay down your reasons a little bit?

Comment: the calls should be handled by one user only, so an authentication against it should not be that hard. 
The difficulty for me is to "route" the requests and repectifly it's answer back to the caller

Comment: The Rest API uses oAuth and the other side (which should speak to the API) can not use oAuth authentication, so I want to stack the authentication in another webservice to handle this.

Comment: What type of authorization is used in API? If you want to access the token, you can implement it when it receives any request, perform authorization on target API, execute a request from `MessageHeader`, execute this request on target API, which requires authorization and return the response as is

Comment: How about making a proxy that intercepts the authetication calls but passes everything else through to the API?

Comment: the idea of a proxy sounds good to me and would be the scope. 
Should this be implemented as a secondary service, or how would this look like?

Comment: Depends a little on how fully featured you want it. I don't have any experience with proxies, but a quick Google search gave me this that might be useful: https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy